# Is an infinitesimally small portion of a surface essentially a 2-D area? (Surface Integrals)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to derive the equation for surface flux

$$\iint_{S}\vec F\cdot \hat n \;dS $$

So far, I understand that if we consider the vector field going through smooth surface. Then the flux on a small piece of the surface, or surface element, $\Delta S$, is  given by the contribution of $\vec F$ in the direction of the unit normal $\hat n$, times the piece $\Delta S$

$$\vec F\cdot \hat n \Delta s$$

Stewart's Calculus then suggests that this portion $\Delta S$ is essentially $\Delta A$, a 2-D area.

My question is if an infinitesimally small portion of a surface is essentially a 2-D area somewhat like a plane?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to think about in 3 dimensions, but more formality is needed when talking about higher dimensions. Yes, it is true that the surface of a solid is 2 dimensional, because we would need exactly 2 parameters to parameterize it. This is the same reason why a space curve is one dimensional even though it travels through 3D space - because we can parameterize some curve $C$ using a **single variable** function $\mathbf{r}: t \mapsto \mathbf{r}(t)$.